# Replace subsequent rows based on time difference and values in other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
index <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1")
c1 <- c("pos", "neg", "neg", "pos", "neg", "neg", "pos", "neg")
orderdate <- c("2018-09-14", "2020-08-20", "2018-09-15", "2019-08-25", "2017-09-12", "2018-09-16", "2020-08-21", "2018-08-10")
df <- data.frame(customerid, index, c1, orderdate)
```

I want to create a new column c2 based on the values in "c1" and "orderdate." The column "index" counts the number of entries for each "customerid."

For each customerid, we look at each result in c1 (pos or neg) by order date from earliest to latest.

1. If c1 is "pos", then that row in c2 is NA and all later rows in c2 for that customerid are "No."
2. If c1 is "neg", then that row in c2 is NA. From here, there are 2 options:
   A) All later rows with orderdate **≤ 500 days** from the earliest order date within a customerid are "No".
   B) Alternatively, the first row with orderdate **> 500 days** from the earliest order date within a customerid is "Yes". This entry becomes the new "earliest result" and we repeat steps 1-2AB (depending on whether it is "pos" or "neg") with it.
3. Of note, if a row already has a value from the 1st condition, the 1st condition takes precedence and it is left alone. For example, if the first result was "pos" for a customer, all of that customerid's c2 entries would be "No". Their entries in c1 and orderdates won't matter.

Each customerid is independent of each other. The result should be:

```
c2 <- c(NA, "No", NA, "No", NA, "No", "Yes", NA)
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I tried various solutions using lead, lag, dplyr, +(any...) and am not getting the correct output. Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is some sample code with additional options for c1 besides pos and neg.

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
index <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1")
c1 <- c("pos", "lost", "neg", "return", "neg", "neg", "lost", "lost")
orderdate <- c("2018-09-14", "2020-08-20", "2018-09-15", "2019-08-25", "2017-09-12", "2018-09-16", "2020-08-21", "2018-08-10")
df <- data.frame(customerid, index, c1, orderdate)
```

Comment: Please don't delete the text of your question. I will attempt to roll back to a version that has some information, but might not get the right version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
process <- function(index_col, c1_col, date_col) {
  earliest_order_date <- min(date_col)
  pos_trip = FALSE
  date_trip = FALSE
  out = c()
  for (i in 1:length(index_col)) {
    if (pos_trip) { # if the positive flag has been raised, keep on returning NAs
      out[i] = "No"
  } else if (c1_col[i] == "pos") { # if the current row is positive, raise the positive flag. Every value after this will be NA 
    out[i] = NA
    pos_trip = TRUE
  } else if (c1_col[i] == "neg") { 
      if (!date_trip) { # if we find the first "neg", then raise the date flag. Every value after this will be either "No" or "Yes", depending on their distance from the earliest date
        out[i] = NA
        date_trip = TRUE
    } else if  (date_col[i] <= earliest_order_date + 500) { # if the date is within 500 days of the earliest date, return "No"
        out[i] = "No"
    } else if  (date_col[i] > earliest_order_date + 500) { # if the date is more than 500 days from the earliest date, return "Yes", and update the earliest date to the current date
        out[i] = "Yes"
        earliest_order_date <- date_col[i]
      }
  }
  }
  return(out) # return the vector of values
}

df %>% 
    mutate(orderdate = as.Date(orderdate)) %>%
    group_by(customerid) %>%
    mutate(c2 = process(index, c1, orderdate))
```

Comment: I just cleaned up the second bit, should work better now

Comment: For the function process, I keep getting an error that it has an unmatched {. thank you!

Comment: try that! I don't know if it matches what you had in mind, but you should be able to use as the basis for what you had in mind

Comment: thank you! are you able to explain the process function a little bit? I think I understand most of what you are doing

Comment: I would honestly ask you to explain it to me! It just loops through the rows. There are some bools (e.g. `pos_trip`) that flip after the first time something happens

Comment: It's unclear what happens to ones with orderdate == 500 days after earliest, also orderdate > 500 days after earliest, after the initial one

Comment: Just updated my post! Please let me know if there is anything still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: new update! I think I understand now

Comment: re: `return` and `lost`- yes, another couple of if statements are needed for that, unless maybe the code was to be refactored

Comment: Can you give an example for return and lost? I added some sample code in my origina post. The result c2 should still be the same.

Comment: The second to last one is NA because the first instance of "pos" **for each customer** is coded as NA. If you want it to go across customers, that's an entirely different kettle of fish.

Comment: pandas123 I think you can do it! It's literally the same as what I have done, just with other values. At a certain point, I'm not answering new things, I'm just providing a code writing service, which is not what StackOverflow is for

Comment: it sounds like you should calculate the across all customerid things first, using a similar function to the one I wrote, and maybe return a column of TRUEs and FALSEs, which can then be used as another input for the `process` function, to check if the row meets your criteria related to those things

Comment: What you're doing doesn't sound impossible, it just sounds complicated, with all of the if statements  maybe have a go, and post some of your code if you get weird errors?

Comment: use `debug`, run the function again, figure out where the code isn't doing what you wanted it to do