# Changing a different number of subsequent entries in a row based on values from other rows

Tags: r

****EDIT: *NEW question that has not been answered by the responses below or in other SO questions. Is there a way to do this with for-loops and iterating through orders based on customerid and order_date? Or by using elseif, etc in dplyr??****

I want to create a new column `summary` based on the values in `order_result` and `order_date`. The column `orders` is the number of orders for each `customer`.

I have the following code -

```
customer <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E", "F", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K")
order <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
order_result <- c("positive", "lost", "negative", "return", "negative", "lost", "negative", "lost", "lost", "return", "lost", "return", "lost", "negative", "lost", "lost", "positive", "return", "negative", "lost", "lost","positive", "lost", "return", "negative", "lost", "lost", "negative")
order_date <- c("2018-09-14", "2020-08-20", "2018-09-15", "2019-08-25", "2017-09-12", "2018-09-16", "2020-08-21", "2018-08-10", "2017-09-13", "2018-02-16", "2020-08-21", "2017-05-20", "2018-07-05", "2019-02-15", "2021-11-04", "2017-08-07", "2021-08-05", "2019-07-30", "2020-09-23", "2020-11-23","2017-10-30", "2018-04-09", "2020-04-09", "2019-07-30", "2019-12-04", "2020-04-04", "2020-08-03", "2021-12-24")
df1 <- data.frame(customer, order, order_result, order_date)
```

I want to parse through order_results for each customer from earliest to latest order_date and create a new column `summary` with yes or no entries. The 1st order for a customer always is "yes" in the `summary` column, and we keep moving down the list of orders for each customer. As we go through the `orders` based on the order_date (earliest to latest) for each customer, we look at the `order_result` to determine how many rows to fill out in `summary` and with what value. Say we start with an index order. If the `order_result` is "negative", then an unspecified number of later rows in `summary` for that customer are either "no" if their `order_date` is ≤400 days from the index order or yes if >400 days from the index `order_date`. The number of rows to fill out with "no" depends on the actual order_dates, which can vary based on customer. If the `order_result` is "return" or "lost", the next order has "yes" in `summary`. If the `order_result` is "positive", all later orders for that patient have "no" in `summary`. We move down the list of orders by jumping to the next order that has yes in `summary` (which becomes the next index order) and repeating.

Each customerid is independent of each other. The result should be:

```
summary <- c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")
```

My question is I am not sure how to approach filling out an unspecified number of rows  with "no" since it all depends on the actual order_dates and the elapsed time from the index date. In addition, how can I jump from 1 row with "yes" to the next row with "yes" in `summary` (ie, change index dates) for the same customer (not the whole dataset) and repeat the process all over again? I tried using lag/lead but was not getting the correct output. Thanks!

****EDIT:**** Here is my pseudocode:

```
if (order == 1) {
  summary == 'TRUE'}  #first order for a customer is always TRUE. 
if (order_result[row_number()] == 'positive') {   #If result is positive
  summary[row_number()+ length(?)] == FALSE} #After a positive result, all subsequent rows in summary for that customer are FALSE.
if (order_result[row_number()] == 'negative') {   #If result is negative, there are 2 options based on time difference between that order date and subsequent order dates. 
  if (diff_time(orderdate[row_number()], orderdate[row_number(?)]) <= 400 {  
    summary[row_number()+ length(?)] == FALSE}   #After a negative result, all subsequent rows under summary within 400 days of that order for that customer are FALSE
  else summary[row_number()+ length(?)] == TRUE}  #Otherwise all subsequent rows in summary over 400 days for that customer are TRUE
if (order_result[row_number()] == 'lost' | order_result[row_number()] == 'return')  {
  summary[row_number() + 1] == TRUE}  #If order result is lost or return, the next order for that customer is true under summary.
}
```

Comment: Two inferences from your sample data, please confirm: (1) customers always have two rows; (2) "positive"/"negative" can only occur in the first row for a particular customer, all subsequent rows will be either "return" or "lost". If either of those are not true, I suggest you update your sample data to cover a little more varied dataset.

Comment: Strong Deja-vu vibes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569443/replace-subsequent-rows-based-on-time-difference-and-values-in-other-column-in-r

Comment: No, customers do not always have 2 rows: sometimes they just have 1 row. Positive/negative/return/lost can occur in any row in any particular order. Updated the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your comment, here is the updated code

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(new=ifelse(order==1, 'Yes', NA),
         lag=ifelse(order!=1,lag(order_date), NA),
         diff=as.Date(order_date)-as.Date(lag),
         negpos=ifelse(order==1 & order_result %in% c('positive','negative'),order_result,NA_character_),
         negpos2=ifelse(order!=1 & !order_result %in% c('positive','negative'),order_result,NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  fill(negpos,negpos2) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(summary=case_when(
    order!=1 & order_result=='negative' & negpos=='negative' & negpos2 %in% c('lost','return') ~ 'Yes',
    order!=1 & diff<=400 & negpos=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & diff>400 & negpos=='negative' ~ 'Yes',
    order==1 ~ 'Yes',
    order!=1 & order_result %in% c('lost','return') & negpos=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & negpos=='positive' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & is.na(negpos) & !is.na(negpos2) ~ 'Yes',
    order!=1 & diff<=400 & order_result=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & diff>400 & order_result=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & order_result=='positive' ~ 'No'
  )) %>% select(-c(new,lag,negpos,negpos2,diff))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   customer order order_result order_date summary
   <chr>    <chr> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>  
 1 A        1     positive     2018-09-14 Yes    
 2 A        2     lost         2020-08-20 No     
 3 B        1     negative     2018-09-15 Yes    
 4 B        2     return       2019-08-25 No     
 5 C        1     negative     2017-09-12 Yes    
 6 C        2     lost         2018-09-16 No     
 7 C        3     negative     2020-08-21 Yes    
 8 D        1     lost         2018-08-10 Yes    
 9 E        1     lost         2017-09-13 Yes    
10 E        2     return       2018-02-16 Yes    
11 E        3     lost         2020-08-21 Yes    
12 F        1     return       2017-05-20 Yes
```

Comment: Is there a way to use for loops to solve this problem by iterating through orders based on customerid and order_date? Thanks!

Comment: since this involves the derivation of only single variable based on the multiple conditions , loop is not an ideal approach

Comment: Does your current solution take the order of results into account? I was trying to adapt it but the only way I could think of was using a loop with indexing. All solutions are welcome!

Comment: i believe it does take into account, could you please check this on your actual data to confirm

Comment: you can test the code and check

Comment: is it possible to include those scenarios in the sample data

Comment: yes I just updated the dataframe and desired output! Of note, in addition to the lag function (see customer "K"), some summary entries are incorrectly NA in later orders if the 1st order is "lost" or "returned". I added those examples as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254361/discussion-between-jkatam-and-pandas123).

Answer (score 1):

Please check

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(new=ifelse(order==1, 'Yes', NA),
  lag=ifelse(order!=1,lag(order_date), NA),
  diff=as.Date(order_date)-as.Date(lag),
  negpos=ifelse(order==1 & order_result %in% c('positive','negative'),order_result,NA_character_),
  negpos2=ifelse(order!=1 & !order_result %in% c('positive','negative'),order_result,NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  fill(negpos,negpos2) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(summary=case_when(
    order!=1 & order_result=='negative' & negpos=='negative' & negpos2 %in% c('lost','return') ~ 'Yes',
    order!=1 & diff<=400 & negpos=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & diff>400 & negpos=='negative' ~ 'Yes',
    order==1 ~ 'Yes',
    order!=1 & order_result %in% c('lost','return') & negpos=='negative' ~ 'No',
    order!=1 & negpos=='positive' ~ 'No'
    )) %>% select(-c(new,lag,negpos,negpos2,diff))

# output

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  customer order order_result order_date summary
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>  
1 A        1     positive     2018-09-14 Yes    
2 A        2     lost         2020-08-20 No     
3 B        1     negative     2018-09-15 Yes    
4 B        2     return       2019-08-25 No     
5 C        1     negative     2017-09-12 Yes    
6 C        2     lost         2018-09-16 No     
7 C        3     negative     2020-08-21 Yes    
8 D        1     lost         2018-08-10 Yes
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you used negpos and negpos2? And the use of fill? Thank you!

Comment: I used the `fill` to retain the positive or negative values in `negpos` and return or lost in '`negpos2', based on these i tried to use the ifelse conditions

Comment: What about the use of new? It doesn't show up in casewhen?

Comment: it is not used so can be ignored

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a way to use for loops to solve this problem by iterating through orders based on customerid and order_date? Thanks!

Comment: yes, there is a way, but i am unable to do it. may be its for an expert