# How to index each subset after split() for a for-loop

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop where we run through the entire dataset by running through each mini-dataframe separately based on customerid.

I think I can split up this dataframe by `customerid` using split() and index each unique component for a for-loop, kind of like an index within an index. I have the following dataframe with the correct index under `orderid`, but I do not need this actually to be printed out.

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid)
```

I know how to index the list of mini dataframes:

```
customerid_split <- split(df, df$customerid)
for (i in 1:length(customer_split)) {...
```

But I don't know how to index all entries within each mini-dataframe to get something like this:

```
customerid_split <- split(df, df$customerid)
for (i in 1:length(customer_split)) {
    for (j in 1:???*the index for the mini dataframes) {...
```

Thanks! Also, I don't necessarily need to use split(), just figured it would be easier. I want to create a for loop where we run through the entire dataset by running through each mini-dataframe separately based on customerid.

Comment: What are you trying to the dataset after the split?

Comment: You could think about a different approach than a for-loop, e.g. a `purrr` way: `purrr::map(customerid_split, ~.x |> 
             dplyr::mutate(new_col = "info"))`

Comment: I am trying to solve this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76575990/changing-a-different-number-of-subsequent-entries-in-a-row-based-on-values-from

Comment: I thought I could create a for loop where we run through the entire dataset by running through orders within each mini-dataframe, which are independent of each other and based on customerid. Hence this question about nested indexes.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `nrow(customerid_split[[i]])` or `ncol(customerid_split[[i]])` ?

Comment: Does that return the indices of each of the data frames with customer_id? Also, why the [[]] instead of [] if we are still using indices? The specific example is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76575990/changing-a-different-number-of-subsequent-entries-in-a-row-based-on-values-from. Thanks!